# Building vars dynamically

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to leverage ovirt-ansible (https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-ansible) but it's vars are a bit verbose and I'd like to generate them off some simpler ones to reduce the chance of human error.

For example, something like this which obviously doesn't work:

```
vars:
  cluster_name: test
  domain_suffix: blah
  subnet_mgmt: 1.2.3

  myhosts:
    - id: 001
      ip_suffix: 101

  hosts:
   {% for host in myhosts %}
   - name: "{{ cluster_name }}-{{ host[id] }}.{{ domain_suffix }}"
     address: "{{ subnet_mgmt  }}.{{ host[ip_suffix] }}"
   {% endfor %}
```

Can anyone advise best way to go about doing this, without simply forking their repo and rewriting the playbook to read the variables in my own format? I'm hoping to avoid having to maintain a fork going forwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the [code](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples/blob/master/examples/example-022/dynamic_var.yml) that you're looking for?

**> cat dynamic_var.yml**

```
- hosts: localhost                                                                           
  vars:                                                                                      
    cluster_name: test                                                                       
    domain_suffix: blah                                                                      
    subnet_mgmt: 1.2.3                                                                       
    myhosts:                                                                                 
      - { id: "001", ip_suffix: "101" }                                                      
  tasks:                                                                                     
    - set_fact:                                                                              
        hosts:                                                                               
          - name: "{{ cluster_name }}-{{ item.id }}.{{ domain_suffix }}"                     
            address: "{{ subnet_mgmt  }}.{{ item.ip_suffix }}"                               
      loop: "{{ myhosts }}"                                                                  
    - debug:                                                                                 
        msg: "{{ hosts }}"
```

**> ansible-playbook dynamic_var.ym**

(abridged)

```
TASK [debug] 
        "address": "1.2.3.101", 
        "name": "test-001.blah"
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Is it possible to do subloops? Lets say I need to build an array inside of the individual host entry as well?

Comment: Yes. It's possible. Use [subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements). Take a look at the [example](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples/blob/master/examples/example-022/dynamic_array_var.yml)